# Android set and get value from list and save to db sqlite

Tags: android

Hi i would like to know how i can save values from text fields in a listview and save them to myDb independently.

I have two tables parent and child which the data needs to be saved to.

The listview layout has a textview and edittext field whereby the textview field is being populated data from the database and the edittext should save data to the database but in a different table using the textview value id.

[image: Screenshot of UI]

I would like to save the other fields in the screen on parent table and save the listview data on the child table...which should have table id of the parent,and value id of the textview item and the amount being set.

this is my main

```
public class ProducedMilk extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private DatePickerDialog dateto;
EditText txtdate,txtsoldamt;
TextView tvtotalproduced;
Button btnsubmit;
ArrayList<Milk> milkList;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
private ListView cowlist;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_produced_milk);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById (R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar (toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            onBackPressed ();
            Intent intent = new Intent (ProducedMilk.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity (intent);
        }
    });

    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    findViewsById ();
    setDateTimeField ();

    // get Database Handler
    db = new DatabaseHelper (getApplicationContext());

    //Generate ListView from Database
    displayListView ();

    tvtotalproduced=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.totalamt);
    txtsoldamt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cbeamt);
    cowlist = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvadd);
    btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById (R.id.submitmilk);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener (this);
}

private void displayListView () {
    Cursor cursor = db.fetchInMilkCows ();
    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME
    };
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[]
            {
                    R.id.cownamelv
            };
    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.milkproductlv, cursor, columns, to, 0);
    cowlist = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvadd);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    cowlist.setAdapter (dataAdapter);

}

private void findViewsById () {
    txtdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateproduc);
    txtdate.setInputType (InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    txtdate.requestFocus ();
}

private void setDateTimeField () {
    txtdate.setOnClickListener (this);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
    dateto = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener () {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            txtdate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }
    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    if(v == txtdate) {
        dateto.show();
    }
    switch (v.getId ()) {
        case R.id.submitmilk:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to save these details ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String date_produced = txtdate.getText ().toString ();
                            String quantity = txtsoldamt.getText ().toString ();
                            // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                            if (date_produced.equals ("")) {
                                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Field(s) Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                startActivity (refresh);
                            } else {
                                // Save the Data in Database
                                milkList = new ArrayList<Milk>();
                                for(int i = 0; i < cowlist.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                                     new Milk (cowlist.getAdapter ().getItem (i));
                                }
                                db.createMilkProduction (date_produced);
                                db.createSale (date_produced,quantity);
                                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Submitted Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                startActivity (refresh);
                            }
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle ("Produced Milk");
            alert.show ();
    }
}
```

}

this is my handler

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "farmers";
    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "users";
    private static final String TABLE_COW = "cows";
    private static final String TABLE_MILK = "milk";
    private static final String TABLE_SALES= "sales";
    // Common column names
    public static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    // user Table - column names
    public static final String  KEY_USERNAME= "username";
    public static final String  KEY_CODE = "farmerscode";
    public static final String  KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    // cows Table - column names
    public static final String  KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String  KEY_AGE = "age";
    public static final String  KEY_BREED = "breed";
    //public static final String  KEY_COLOR = "color";
    public static final String  KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

    // milk Table - column names
    public static final String KEY_DATE_PRODUCED = "date_produced";
    public static final String KEY_COW = "cow_id";
    public static final String KEY_QTY= "quantity";

    // sales Table - column names
    public static final String KEY_DPRODUCED = "date_produced";
    public static final String KEY_QTY_SOLD = "total_sold";

    // Table Create Statements

    // user table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USER+ "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR,"+ KEY_CODE + " VARCHAR,"       
        + KEY_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR," + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

        // cows table create statement
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COW = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_COW + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+KEY_AGE+ "          NUMERIC,"
        + KEY_BREED + " TEXT,"+ KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "+ KEY_CREATED_AT + "   DATETIME" + ")";


     // milk table create statement
     private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MILK = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MILK+ "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE_PRODUCED + " DATETIME," + KEY_COW + " INTEGER,"+ KEY_QTY + " NUMERIC,"
         + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_COW+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_COW+"("+KEY_ID+"));";

// sales table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SALES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_SALES+ "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DPRODUCED + " DATETIME," + KEY_QTY_SOLD + " NUMERIC,"+ KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME," + ")";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // creating required tables
    db.execSQL (CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    db.execSQL (CREATE_TABLE_COW);
    db.execSQL (CREATE_TABLE_MILK);
    db.execSQL (CREATE_TABLE_SALES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COW);
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MILK);
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SALES);

    // create new tables
    onCreate (db);
}

// ------------------------ "USER" table methods ----------------//

/**
 * Creating a Farmer
 */
public long createUser (String username, String farmerscode, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues ();
    initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, farmerscode);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    return db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * getting user count
 */
public int getuserCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}

/**
 * getting single user
 */
public String getSinlgeEntry(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("users", null, " username=?",
            new String[] { username }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

public String getUsername() throws SQLException {
    String username = "";
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_USERNAME },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            username = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return username;
}
/**
 * getting user
 */
public Cursor fetchUser() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query (TABLE_USER, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                    KEY_USERNAME, KEY_CODE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor fetch() {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery ("Select * from users", null);
resultSet.moveToFirst ();
return resultSet;


public long createCow (String name, String age, String breed, String category) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BREED, breed);
    //initialValues.put(KEY_COLOR, color);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    return db.insert(TABLE_COW, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * getting all cows
 */
public Cursor fetchInMilkCows() {
    String im ="In Milk";
    String query = "SELECT _id,name FROM cows WHERE category ='"+im+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
public Cursor fetchAllCows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query (TABLE_COW, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_BREED, KEY_CATEGORY},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getCowsData(int _id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery( "select * from cows where _id="+_id+"", null );
    return res;
}
/**
 * getting cow count
 */
public int getCowsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COW;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}

public int getCowsMilkCount() {
    String im ="In Milk";
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM cows WHERE category ='"+im+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}


public boolean updateCow (Integer _id, String name, String age, String breed,String category) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(KEY_BREED, breed);
    //contentValues.put(KEY_COLOR, color);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    db.update("cows", contentValues, "_id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(_id) } );
    return true;
}


public ArrayList getAllCows() {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList ();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery( "select * from cows", null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    } return array_list;
}


public Integer deleteCow (Integer _id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("cows", "_id = ? ", new String[] {
            Integer.toString(_id) });
}

/**
 * delete all cows
 */
public int deleteAllCows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_COW, null, null);

}

public long createMilkProduction (String date_produced,Integer cow,String qty_produced) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_PRODUCED, date_produced);
    initialValues.put(KEY_COW,cow);
    initialValues.put(KEY_QTY,qty_produced);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    return db.insert(TABLE_MILK, null, initialValues);
}
/**
 * getting MilkProduction count
 */
public int getMilkcount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MILK;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return count;
}

public long createSale (String date_produced, String quantity) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase ();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put (KEY_DPRODUCED,date_produced);
    initialValues.put(KEY_QTY_SOLD, quantity);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    return db.insert(TABLE_SALES, null, initialValues);
}

public int getSalesDetcount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SALES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return count;
}

// closing database
public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase ();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}

private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat (
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault ());
    Date date = new Date ();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

}

submit button

```
     switch (v.getId ()) {
        case R.id.submitmilk:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to save these details ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String date_produced = txtdate.getText ().toString ();
                            String quantity = txtsoldamt.getText ().toString ();


                           }
                            View v;
                            ArrayList<String> cowmilkamt = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < cowlist.getCount(); i++) {
                                cowlist.getAdapter ().getView (i, null, null);
                                v = cowlist.getChildAt(i);
                                //txtcowamt = (EditText) findViewById (i);
                                txtcowamt = (EditText) v.findViewById (R.id.cowmilkamt);
                                cowmilkamt.add (txtcowamt.getText ().toString ());
                            }

                            String cow=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            String qty_produced=txtcowamt.getText ().toString ();
                            // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                            if (date_produced.equals ("")||qty_produced.equals ("")) {
                                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Field(s) Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                startActivity (refresh);
                            } else {
                                db.createMilkProduction (date_produced, Integer.valueOf (cow), qty_produced);
                                db.createSale (date_produced,quantity);
                                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Submitted Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                startActivity (refresh);
                            }
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle ("Produced Milk");
            alert.show ();
    }
```

Any help will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: post the code you have tried and error you faced

Comment: @UmarAta im just displaying the information and would like to know how to save values from the textfield .This is how im fetching the textview item

public Cursor fetchInMilkCows() {
  String im ="In Milk";
  String query = "SELECT _id,name FROM cows WHERE category ='"+im+"'";
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

  if (cursor != null) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return cursor;
 }

Comment: post the full code please

Comment: @UmarAta in the ui im trying to save the name "njeri" which is being populated from the db as an id and the amount to the db table milk

for all the cows so im assuming that it will be an array since i would like to save each item on its row in the databse

Comment: change this.getReadableDatabase(); to this.getWritableDatabase ();

Comment: ok,,,but that doesnt show how we are getting the values from the textfields

Comment: you already written String date_produced = txtdate.getText ().toString ();
                            String quantity = txtsoldamt.getText ().toString ();

Comment: true but the those are from the textfields which are not in the list...
im talking about the list items

Comment: does your problem is solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this as global

```
Cursor cursor;
```

then use it in

```
private void displayListView () {
 cursor = db.fetchInMilkCows ();
```

then set a listonitemclick listener like this

```
     cowlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

list_Position=position;

        }}
```

also declare list_position field

```
int list_Position;
```

then fetch data from cursor using this position , put this code inside your alert

```
  cursor.move(list_Position);
String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

Comment: Im kinda blunt with this a more detailed answer will help alot

Comment: at which line you got the problem

Comment: the fetch line, how to get the name id in the textview and value in edittext

Comment: lets chat on skype my skype id bryan.munene

Comment: what problem you faced now

Comment: its not a problem,,,its more of a question..
since getColumnIndex gets the id  and name of the item from the database which i only need the id but i also want to get the entered amount for the item

Comment: Thanks alot i finally got it

Comment: i will,i still need two more reputation points to vote but thanks alot you saved me alot of time

Comment: one last thing,,, while im saving only the first edittext values are being recorded .
I have updated my question,you can check how im saving the fields and tell me what im doing wrong or what im i not doing

Comment: store txtdate in a variable too

Comment: not working,,,can the edittext be given unique IDs like lets say in the ui ,we take "njeri" _id and use it as the amount's edittext id

Comment: you may generate a random number at runtime

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: another approach is to add current miliseconds with id of edittext

Comment: im trying to make it as simple as possible since i will be sharing the app so  i was thinking if there would be a way of to give the edittext different id's since as of now theonly record being saved is the first one

Comment: im not familiar to listviews so i hope you understand my concerns

Comment: as I said you may get current miliseconds its also very simple

Comment: or you may use autoincrement id

Comment: it will be good if you share the schema of tables in which you are not able to insert and also update your question with insert code which you applied but dont delete anything from question

Comment: my handler hasn't changed and my insert code is the same one as i had updated earlier...It seems like its just getting one field and ignoring the rest

Answer (score 0):

so i my final working code

```
 switch (v.getId ()) {
        case R.id.submitmilk:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to save these details ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String date_produced = txtdate.getText ().toString ();
                            String quantity = txtsoldamt.getText ().toString ();

                            int count = cowlist.getAdapter().getCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) cowlist.getChildAt (i);
                                // Find by under LinearLayout
                                TextView txtid = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.cowidamt);
                                EditText txtInput = (EditText) itemLayout.findViewById (R.id.cowmilkamt);

                               // String cow = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("_id"));
                                String cow = txtid.getText().toString();
                                String qty_produced = txtInput.getText ().toString ();

                                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                                if (date_produced.equals ("")||qty_produced.equals ("")) {
                                    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Field(s) Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                    Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                    startActivity (refresh);
                                } else {
                                    db.createMilkProduction (date_produced, Integer.valueOf (cow), qty_produced);
                                    db.createSale (date_produced,quantity);
                                    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Submitted Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                    Intent refresh = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), ProducedMilk.class);
                                    startActivity (refresh);
                                }
                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle ("Produced Milk");
            alert.show ();
    }
```